# java split string using ordered array

Tags: java, regex, arrays

I have problems to find a clever solution for the following problem. I have the text String "exp" and a predefind list "chapters" with the number of the chapters. My Goal is to split the text according to the predefined sequential order of the chapters. I have this regex:

```
"(\n(\\d\\.?){1,}?\\S+)"
```

It matches the numeration of the chapters, but how can I check if this matches also first the first element in the chapter list and in the next paragraph if the numbering matches the second element in the chapter list?

```
static String[] chapters;
chapters = new String[]{"1","1.1","1.2"};
String exp = 
"1 HeaderOne
1.1 HeaderOneOne
This is Text in the first Paragraph with the header 1.1.

1.2 HeaderOneTwo
This is Text in the second Paragraph.";
```

Comment: Any problem using Map?

Comment: I dont think regex and split are going to help you. just use recursive calls to `indexOf()`

Comment: I like the idea of determine the start and end of the chapter first and split in the end. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly then do the following.

1. split ur exp by '\n' and add it to list.
2. Call Collections.sort(urSpilitLIst, urComparater);

In side urComparater write sorting logic of ur list. The sorting logic would sort based on order inside ur chapters list.